# How to compile a program in Go

Tags: go, compilation, executable

I know how to run a file in go using `go run file.go`, but I want to compile it to an executable.
When I looked up, I found about `6g` and `6l` and it seems like they are outdated.

I want something like:

```
go-compiler -o output file.go
```

Comment: You can look https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_packages_and_dependencies for details documentation and more available options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want:

```
go build -o executable source.go
```

Comment: Or just `go build` in the package you're in - provided you followed the conventions in https://golang.org/doc/code.html